# Determining differntiability and analyticity of $|z|^2$ and $|x|+i|y|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Where are the following functions differentiable and where are they analytic

## My Solutions

We have

$$|z|^2=x^2-y^2$$

Which is a polynomial, therefore it is differentiable everywhere. However, we can quickly look at the Cauchy-Riemann equations to observe that this function is analytic only at the origin.

I am struggling with this one

$$f(z)=|x|+i|y|$$

As, on the reals the absolute function has some troubles at $0$ but I'm not sure if those issues are alleviated in the complex plane.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your work with the first function is fine.

About the second function, we will have trouble in the axis, because $|\cdot|$ is not differentiable at zero. Now we look at each open quadrant. In the first quadrant, we have $f(z) = z$, which is analytic. In the second quadrant, we have $f(z) = -\overline{z}$, which is not analytic. In the third quadrant, we have $f(z) = -z$, which is analytic. Finally, in the fourth quadrant we have $f(z) = \overline{z}$, which is not analytic.